# SET Variable in a for /f loop not working outside the loop

Tags: batch-file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J73C2.png)I'm trying to SET one or two Variables in a for /f loop and use them outside the loop, but so far I have failed to do so, after hours of trying I finally gave up and ask for somebody to help me. I'm aware of the use of SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION in a batch file but with or without using it it still does not work.
The code so far is:

```
    @echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

curl -s 192.168.1.68/cgi-bin/home | for /f "tokens=1,2,3" %%a in ('Grep -o -P "[0-9].{0,8}kWh.{0,0}"') do (

    set VAR01=%%a
    set VAR02=%%a
)

echo %VAR01%
echo !VAR01!
ENDLOCAL
```

RESULT on Console is:

```
(set VAR01=2.14   & set VAR02=2.14  )

ECHO is off.

ECHO is off.
```

The variable is SET in the loop but outside the loop it is not.

Comment: Result of the echo %VAR01% and the echo !VAR01! is ""/blank,/nothing.

Comment: Yes unfortunately it is, why do you think it is not?

Answer (score 2):

your problem is piping. Both sides of a pipe are executed in their own environment, so your variables are gone as soon as they are finished.

Watch the output of the following two methods (I used standard `cmd` commands, because I don't have `curl` and `grep`, but the result should be the same.

```
echo ON
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

echo hello world|for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in ('findstr "e o"') do (
  set a=%%a
  set b=%%b
)
echo %a% %b%
echo ---------
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in ('echo hello world^|findstr "e o"') do (
  set a=%%a
  set b=%%b
)
echo %a% %b%
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 set VAR01=%%a
 set VAR02=%%a
 goto done
)
:done
echo %VAR01%
```

It's hard to believe that your result is actually as you claim, since there is no `&` on a single line in your code.

I believe that the `for` is executing more than once - the first time it might set the variables, and the second time clear them. Again, this *should* be shown on your trace.

By `goto`ing out of the loop, the variables should be displayed directly after having been set the first time.

The conventional way to do this is

for ... in (`curl... ^|grep...') do (

where the `^` escapes the pipe to make it redirect *within* the quoted command.

Comment: @Maggo: was my first thougt also, but the output is indeed correct (caused by the pipe outside the `for`).

Comment: I have changed it into:
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

curl -s 192.168.1.68/cgi-bin/home | for /f "tokens=1" %%a in ('Grep -o -P "[0-9].{0,8}kWh.{0,0}"')   do (

 SET VAR01=%%a
 SET VAR02=%%a
 SET VAR03=%%a
 goto :done
)
:done
echo %VAR01%
echo %VAR02%
echo %VAR03%



ENDLOCAL

But still the same result, VAR0x is set by the value of %%a inside the loop but outside it is still empty